# How can I increase the identation in org-mode lists?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to use more than two spaces for list indentation. I've had a look at the documentation, but I couldn't find a variable for that. Instead of this:

```
 - First
   - First
   - Second
 - Second
   - First
```

… I would prefer this indentation for better legibility of the indentation levels:

```
 - First
     - First
     - Second
 - Second
     - First
```

Answer (score 4):

I've overlooked the variable that controls it: `org-list-indent-offset`. I've added this now to my configuration:

```
(setq-default org-list-indent-offset 4)
```